# Setting up wxWidgets 3.0 for codeblocks12.11 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: code-blocks

I already downloaded and installed codeblocks 12.11svn9156. After that, I downloaded and compiled wxWidgets3.0 using make. When I go to codeblocks I don't see wxWidgets3.0 in the wxWidget project wizard. Also, the wizard prompts me

> wxSmith plugin is not loaded, can not continue

I know some additional steps have to be done but I only found some confusing documentation.

Comment: Any progress? I'm having the same problem, though I need wxWidgets for a different program.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib
```

http://linux-buddy.blogspot.ca/2014/08/wxsmith-plugin-is-not-loaded-can-not.html